# Entity Framework error when import scalar function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I have an application with C#, I use entity framework to connect at database T-SQL. So I want to call a scalar function. 
When I try to import this function I have a warning message:

> Avviso    1   Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of
>   the store function 'F_GetCodiceAppezzamento'. The store function will
>   be ignored and the function import will not be
>   generated.    C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Source\Workspaces\OmniaFarm\ws\WSOmniaFarm\WSOmniaFarm\FarmGEO_ToolEntities.edmx    1   1   WSOmniaFarm

So I have insert this method into FarmGeoo_ToolEntities class:

```
[DbFunction("FarmGEO_ToolEntities.Store", "F_GetCodiceAppezzamento")]
public string F_GetCodiceAppezzamento(string partitaIva)
{
            var lObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

            return lObjectContext.
                CreateQuery<string>(
                    "FarmGEO_ToolEntities.F_GetCodiceAppezzamento",
                    new ObjectParameter("PIVAImpresa", partitaIva)).
                Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking).
                FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But when I try to call this method I have error:

> 'F_GetCodiceAppezzamento' non definito nel contenitore di entità
>   'FarmGEO_ToolEntities'. Vicino identificatore semplice, riga 1,
>   colonna 34."}

Comment: Last time I tried EF doesn't support Scalar Functions.  Looks like it created the code on the generation but look into the model browser to see if it actually created it under the "Function Imports". If it's there, what is the return type on the Scalar Function?  Table-Valued Functions do work in EF so you might use that as a cheat.